# How to create an empty list of a specific runtime type

Tags: list, f#

Given a the .Net Type, say `typeof<string>`, at runtime how does one created the equivalent of `string list = []`?

My motivation is that when using `FSharpValue.MakeRecord` to create a record based on values parsed the values need to be passed as a `obj[]`. I've been up casting the arguments using `box` and that has worked except for with lists. The issue I've encountered is that a empty untyped list list can't be boxed and then unboxed. The specific error returned is:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 
'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.Object]' 
to type 
'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpList`1[System.String]'.
```

An empty typed list can be boxed and unboxed so I've tried to find a way to cast a list to a runtime type, e.g. a Type returned by typeof<> but with no luck.

```
type Test = {Names : string list}
// fails
let genericList = []
{Names = unbox (box genericList)}

//works
let typedList : string list = []
{Names = unbox (box typedList)}

//works
let genericNonEmptyList = ["Bill"]
{Names = unbox (box genericNonEmptyList)}
```

Comment: This can be done using reflection.  However in general it is indicative that you should rethink you design

Comment: Wouldn't Seq.cast do what you want? Sorry if I misunderstandt the OP: `genericList |> Seq.cast<string>`.

Comment: John, any clues how to do this with reflection? I've "ahem" cast about quite a bit looking for the way but as far as I can see there is no explicit way to do this.

Answer (score 5):

Let me add one more alternative answer - although both of the existing methods work, they rely on understanding how F# represents lists. In the first case, you need to know there is `Empty` method and in the second case, you need to know there is a union case called `Empty`.

I generally prefer to do this by defining a helper type and using reflection over my custom type:

```
type ListHelper =
  static member Empty<'T>() : list<'T> = []

let makeEmpty =
  let empty = typeof<ListHelper>.GetMethod("Empty")
  let emptyArr : obj[] = [| |]
  fun ty -> empty.MakeGenericMethod([| ty |]).Invoke(null, emptyArr)
```

This gives you quite simple function that can cache the `MethodInfo` (you could even use `Expression` to pre-compile and cache the invocations) and does not rely on clever tricks.

Comment: This is a good alternative, but determining the name of a union case at runtime isn't hard: `let name = let (Quotations.Patterns.NewUnionCase(uc,_)) = <@ [] @> in uc.Name`.

Comment: Unfortunately like the solutions of @kvb and @CaringDev this does not seem to do quite the right thing. Running `makeEmpty typeof<string>' for example gives back a signature `val it : obj = []` but what is needed is `val it : string list = []`

Comment: @jbeeko You can add `:?> string list` to cast the result - but if you are using reflection, then I assumed you do not statically know the type of the elements (you only have runtime `System.Type`). If you knew the type statically, you would not need reflection at all.

Comment: @TomasPetricek I must be missing something. I was hoping for an empty list that can be used where a list of stings is expected. But even the following does not compile `List.append (makeEmpty typeof<string>) ["foo"]`.

`This expression was expected to have type
    'a list
but here has type
    obj`

Comment: @jbeeko In this context, you can just use standard `List.empty` function - you do not need reflection `List.append List.empty ["foo"]` (this is because in this context, the type is statically known).

Answer (score 4):

Using reflection you can get the `List` module and call the generic `empty` method:

```
open System
open System.Reflection

let emptyList (t:Type) =
    Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<_ list>)
        .GetType("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule")
        .GetMethod("Empty", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
        .MakeGenericMethod(t)
        .Invoke(null, [||])
```

use as follows:

```
let itemType = typeof<string>
let emptyStringList = emptyList(itemType) :?> string list
```

If you are calling that quite often, consider caching (reduces execution time by ~1/3):

```
let emptyList =
    let empty =
        Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof<_ list>)
            .GetType("Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.ListModule")
            .GetMethod("Empty", BindingFlags.Static ||| BindingFlags.Public)
    fun (t:Type) -> empty.MakeGenericMethod(t).Invoke(null, [||])
```

Answer (score 2):

[@CaringDev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2894770/caringdev)'s answer using .NET reflection is fine, but you can also use the F#-specific reflection module to create instances of union cases:

```
let empty ty = 
    let uc = 
        Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typedefof<_ list>.MakeGenericType [|ty|]) 
        |> Seq.filter (fun uc -> uc.Name = "Empty") 
        |> Seq.exactlyOne
    Reflection.FSharpValue.MakeUnion(uc, [||])
```

Comment: I like how this is succinct and makes use of the fact that Lists are union types. Will caching `Reflection.FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typedefof<_ list>` help performance similar to the suggestion by @caringdev?

Comment: No, unlike a generic `MethodInfo`, there's no such thing as a generic `UnionCaseInfo`, so there's no analogous approach.  In non-generic cases, you'd probably want to cache and use the result of `FSharpValue.PreComputeUnionConstructor` instead of calling `FSharpValue.MakeUnion`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm way late to the party, but I was trying to do the same thing.  I found a way to do this with pattern matching:

```
let emptyListFromExample e =
    match [e] with
    | [] -> []
    | x::xs -> xs
```

This will give you an empty list of any type, provided you can construct a value of that type to start it off.

Answer (score 0):

How about using [Seq.cast](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/seq.cast%5B't%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) to cast the empty generic list?

```
type Test = {Names : string list}
let genericList = []
let test = {Names = unbox (box genericList ) |> Seq.cast<string> |> Seq.toList}
test.Names //val it : string list = []
```

Comment: Indeed `[] |> Seq.cast<string> |> Seq.toList` works but only if the compile time type `string` is know. In my case I am building a list at runtime having been passed in the runtime `Type`. In this case I can't do the above because a runtime type what you get from typeof<string> can't be used.

Comment: I see. I was afraid that is going to be an issue. :-(